# Finding the number of occurrences of various groups in a list

Tags: python-3.x

`So,I am given a list-

```
group = [2,1,3,4]
```

Each index of this list represents a group.
So `group 0 = 2`

```
group 1 = 1
group 2 = 3 
group 3 = 4
```

I am given another list called :

```
l =[[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 1]], [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]
```

the output I want is:

```
dict = {0:[0,3],1;[1],2:[2,3],3:[0,2]}
```

If the number of times the element appears in each sublist of l ie if both l[0][0] and l[0][1] have 0's appear 2 times, it is added to the index 0 of the dict.  Since both `l[0][0]` and `l[0][1]` have 3 appear 4 times(this is because group[3] is 4), it is added to the index 0.
now in `l[1][0]` and 0 appears just once(instead of twice) so its not added to index 1. However 1 just appears once so it is added to index 1.Thanks!

What I have tried so far:

```
def tryin(l,groups):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            if j in (l[i][j]):
                count+=1
                if count == groups[i]:
                    print(i,j)
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far ?

Comment: The code shown above but it doesn't work

Comment: What should be the output for this example ?
l=[[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] groups = g=[4,1,2,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

input:

```
group = [2,1,3,4]
l =[[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 1]], [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]



def IntersecOfSets(list_):
    result = set(list_[0])
    for s in list_[1:]:
        result.intersection_update(s)

        return result
def nb_occ(l,group):
    d = {}
    for i in l:
        l2=[]
        for j in i:
            l1 = []
            for x in group:

                if j.count(group.index(x)) >= x :
                    y=group.index(x)
                    l1.append(y)
            l2.append(l1)
        if len(l2)>1:
            d[str(l.index(i))]= IntersecOfSets(l2)
        else:
            d[str(l.index(i))]= l2[0]
    return d
print(nb_occ(l,group))
```

output:

```
{'2': {2, 3}, '1': [1], '0': {0, 3}, '3': {0, 2}}
```

Comment: l=[[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
groups = g=[4,1,2,3]

Comment: you should group them in sub listed every group of lists together i will check what's wrong with this example and i will update my code

Comment: in the above code we should have a sub group of list with 2 lists some thhing like that l=[[[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]

Comment: l =[[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 1]], [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]

Comment: groups = [2,1,3,4]

Comment: desired output: {0:[0,3],1;[1],2:[2,3],3:[0,2]}

Comment: Sorry about that error before but for the above case there is an error

Comment: i already update the code it works like what are you looking for and i think that your desired output is worng because the sub list of [0,1] will return 1:[0,1] not only [1] @ksammy926

Comment: the sublist of [0,1] will return 1 as it goes to groups and checks the number at index 0. The number is 2 so 0 must appear two times to make it to the sublist. Since 0 just appears once, it is not added to the sublist.

Comment: i think that you edit your question so i will try to update my code with the new informations

Comment: @ksammy926 i edit the code it works now by the edited problem i hope this will help you